# Clear Cache in spring mvc 3 in internet explorer and chrome

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-3

My Code is this , It works only in mozilla firefox

```
 <%        
response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setDateHeader("Expires",0);
%>
 <c:if test="${empty Sess_Var}" >
<%
response.sendRedirect("doLogin.obj");
%>
```

How to Clear Cache in internet explorer and Chrome?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `private, max-age=0` to the `Cache-Control` header.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private, max-age=0");
```

Note this won't clear the cache. It'll just indicate to the browser that the content shouldn't be cached.

Also, try setting the `Expires` header to -1.

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
```